# Get length of HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

How I can get file size of Apache's POI `HSSFWorkbook`?

I have code like

```
// inside Servlet
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
hSSFWorkbook.write(out);
```

And I want to add `Content-Length` header to response.

Comment: Never worked with POI, but i see their Javadocs listing getBytes() returning a byte array from which you calculate the byte size.

Comment: @asgs sorry, but I use `Workbook` (interface), not `HSSFWorkbook` (implementation) . Forget to menton it.

Answer (score 4):

Best bet is to buffer it somewhere, eg

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(baos);

int length = baos.size();
// Send length...

// Send data
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write( baos.toByteArray() );
out.close();
```

You could use a temp file instead if you wanted to avoid using memory to buffer in

POI will only calculate the size at the time it needs to write everything out, as working out the sizing is almost half the work of writing out! So, you're best off getting the size and the serialisation in one go